# What exactly does runInNewContext do?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently learning some code-base, and it has used `runInNewContext` more often, I tried looking up for but there is no proper definition.

Reading the [official docs](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runinnewcontext_code_sandbox_filename) specifies, all I could understand is the `code` is complied into the `sandbox` specified. What exactly does that mean, for example, there is a bit of code in the code-base that goes something like:

```
request(url, function(error, response, body) {
var subject = {}
try
  vm.runInNewContext(body, subject, url);
  deferred.resolve(subject);
catch _error
  console.log(_error);
}
```

What exactly happens here is confusing me.

Seeing this, I tried to toy around by passing a different object instead of body, but it spits out "Unexpected identifier".

Answer (score 7):

`runInNewContext` creates a new "context" or "sandbox" in which the code runs.

Say, for example, you have a chunk of code you want to run, which is loaded as a string. Just `eval`-ing the string can be dangerous, and gives you little control over what variables and globals this code has.

So, instead, you can create a sandbox, a new context, in which this code can be run. Further, you can "preset" variables that you want available, whether as contexts or as a way to pass things into the context.

So say your code looks like this:

```
var code = "var add = function(a,b){return a + b;}; add(one,two);";
```

This is a function, defined in a string, that adds two numbers, and then actively adds `one` and `two`. What are `one` and `two`? Right now they are undefined. But if you run it in a new context, you can (reasonably) safely run the string code and even define `one` and `two`:

```
vm.runInNewContext(code,{one:1,two:2});
```

which will cause the code to run and `add(1,2)`. A more useful example might be to save it.

```
var result = 0, code = "var add = function(a,b){return a + b;}; result = add(one,two);";
vm.runInNewContext(code,{one:1,two:2,result:result});
console.log(result); // spits out 3
```

Notice that we created a variable `result` in our sandbox context, so that the code in `code` could set it.

I used it in cansecurity's declarative authorization, where you can set an expression to be evaluated and the output will only pass if the result is `true`. https://github.com/deitch/cansecurity look at https://github.com/deitch/cansecurity/blob/master/lib/declarative.js#L96

In that case, I actually take the result. For example, my code might be

```
var str = "user.id === req.user || user.role === 'admin'";
var authorized = vm.runInNewContext(str,{user:{id:"10",name:"John"},user:{role:"member",id:"10"}, req:{user:"20"}});
console.log(authorized); // spits out false, because user.id !== req.user, and user.role !== "admin"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. As you said, the code compiles into the sandbox environment provided, what If i pass an empty object as sandbox, for exampled used the in the code I mentioned in the question? Whether, the code I pass as string will be out as an Object? since it is an empty object?.

Comment: I didn't understand the question. If the sandbox is an empty object, then there are no global vars declared and available inside the code executed from your string. The output will always be the result of `vm.runInNewContext`. Does that answer?

Comment: BTW, your new context is *totally* isolated. It won't even have `require` or `process` any other such unless you pass it in.

Comment: Avec plaisir (my French for the day...)

Comment: I tried and passed the `code` argument as a `String` from the request response with empty object as sandbox, and it returned an `Object` type, just like JSON.parse does. so, I can use this for better conversion in ASYNC calls?

Comment: What do you mean by "better conversion in async calls"?